# Stacking div over another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve something like the image I've attached

[image]

And this is what I'm trying to do in css but couldn't get it to work.

```css
#div_1 {
  width: 90%;
  background: #FBFBFB;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#div_2 {
  height: 110%;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-left: 60%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #FBFBFB;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<div id="div_wrapper">
  <div id="div_1">
    <div id="div_2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Give `position: relative` to the *parent* and `position: absolute` to the *child element*, which will make sure that the *child* is positioned relative to the *parent element*. Then you can place it wherever you want based on the appropriate `top` and `left` *positioning* properties which replaced the unnecessary *margins*:

```css
#div_1 {
  position: relative; /* added */
  width: 90%;
  background: #FBFBFB;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

#div_2 {
  position: absolute; /* added */
  height: 110%; 
  width: 30%;
  top: -5%; /* modified */
  left: 60%; /* modified */
  background: #FBFBFB;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="div_wrapper">
  <div id="div_1">
    Div 1
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="div_2">
      Div 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below snippet. You need not mention `.child` div's height as it will be calculated when you set `top` and `bottom`.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 5% auto;  
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
}
.child{
  position: absolute;
  top:-5%;
  bottom:-5%;
  right: 10%;
  width: 30%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to set your wrapper div position as relative and set it's display property to block.

Now you can set your desired width and height to the wrapper.

Wrapper is marked with red dashed line.

[image: Set your wrapper]

Now you have to set the height for the child elements to expand to their wrapper div.
You can do that by providing a

```
height: 100%
```

to div1
[image: Set height]

Next is to align child items to their parent element.

Usually to align a child element to it's parent you can set the position of parent as relative and child as absolute.

You can set `position: absolute` to div2 and `position:relative` to div1
I would suggest to set the location of div2 using top and left rather than margin-top and margin-left.
[image: Align div2]

Here is a very nice explanation about positions and the common mistakes:

https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

and here https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/ you can find some tips on how to position parent and child elements.

I have modified your code a bit, have a look at it here:

```css
   #div_wrapper {
     display: block;
     position: relative;
     height: 200px;  /* Change to whatever height you like */
     width: 400px;  /* Change to whatever width you like */
     top: 50px;  /* Just for demo */
     left: 10px; /* Just for demo */
   }
   
   #div_1 {
     display: block;
     position: relative;  /* Added */
     width: 90%;
     height: 100%;  /* Added */
     background: #FBFBFB;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
   }
   
   #div_2 {
     position: absolute; /* Added */
     height: 110%;
     width: 30%;
     top: -5%;   /* Modified */
     left: 60%; /* Modified */
     vertical-align: top;
     background: #FBFBFB;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
   }
```

```html
<div id="div_wrapper">
  <div id="div_1">
    <div id="div_2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code it can be work for you may be. You will see effect when "#div_1" have content or height.

```
#div_1 {
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  background: #FBFBFB;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#div_2 {
  width: 30%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5%;
  bottom: -5%;
  left: 60%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #FBFBFB;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    #div_wrapper{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #div_1 {
        width: 90%;
        background: #FBFBFB;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        height: 300px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #div_2 {
            position: absolute;
            height: 120%;
            width: 30%;
            right: 5%;
            top:-10%;
            background: #FBFBFB;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);         
        }
</style>
<div id="div_wrapper">
    <div id="div_1"> div 1
        <div id="div_2">div 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this layout it would be good, if you use `position:absolute` for `div_2` ID and `position:relative` for `div_1` ID, this will let you position the child div anywhere relative to the parent and it is dependent on the height of `div_1`.

```css
#div_1 {
  width: 90%;
  background: #FBFBFB;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#div_2 {
  width: 30%;
  position:absolute;
  right:10%;
  top:-10px;
  bottom:-10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #FBFBFB;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
#div_wrapper{
  text-align:center;
  margin:50px 0px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="div_wrapper">
  <div id="div_1">test
    <div id="div_2">test2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sarabjit Does this answer help you?